# How to compare values in list<string> aganist list<list<string>>

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

///  valid list

```
    List<List<string>> newTestList = new List<List<string>>();
    t.Add(new List<string>() { "A", "A" });
    t.Add(new List<string>() { "B", "WILDCARD", "A" });
    List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "O", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A" };


        List<List<string>> t = new List<List<string>>();
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "A", "A" });
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "B", "W",  })
         t.Add(new List<string>() { "A","S" });
        List<string> cart = new List<string>() { "O", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A","S" };
```

//INvalid List

```
        List<List<string>> t = new List<List<string>>();
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "A", "A" });
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "B", "W", "A","D" });
        List<string> cart = new List<string>() { "O", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A" };

              List<List<string>> t = new List<List<string>>();
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "A", "A" });
        t.Add(new List<string>() { "A","B", "W", "A","D" });
        List<string> cart = new List<string>() { "O", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A" };
```

How to comapre values in testList to values in newTestList .

I want to comapre values in the testList  aganist the newTestList . the second element in the testlist matches matches with the first element of first list in the newTestList 3rd element matches with second element, 4th element matches with the first element of the second list in the newTestList  so on it matches the all elements in the testList in sequence. "WILDCARD" can match any element

Comment: I suggest edit answer and include a few examples with input data and expected results. Also please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do but if it's what it looks like where you having trouble using LINQ against `List<List<string>>` try using var instead and access it with an index like so as a quick example:

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "A", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A" };
List<string> cart = new List<string>() { "O", "A", "A", "B", "O", "A", "S" };

        var Lists = new[]
        {
            testList,
            cart,
            new List<string>() { "A", "A" },
            new List<string>() { "A", "S" }
        };

        IEnumerable<int> answer = from x in Lists[0]
                                  join y in Lists[3] on x.IndexOf("A") equals y.IndexOf("A")
                                  select x.Length + y.Length;
```

Comment: Your trying to add a list to `t` before it has been initialised. I'm guessing you meant to write `newTestList` for the purposes of this question. It's still not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you just want the Lists or strings inside the Lists returned that match between `newTestList` and `testList` then use `intersect` as seen in this link... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/linq-expect-intersect-and-union-method-operator-in-C-Sharp/